# Direct writing a disk results in error code 5 according to GetLastError

Tags: c++, windows, disk, getlasterror

I am trying to direct write a USB disk in Windows. I used the `CreateFile` function to create a disk handle and used the `WriteFile` function to try to write the file. The WriteFile function failed with status code 5 (according to GetLastError). I tried to lock the disk volume by using `FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME`, but the volume was hidden, so I could not get its volume letter.

Code:

```
    u8 Disk::Init()
    {
        char fn[24] = { 0 };
        sprintf(fn, "\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive%d", (int)m_nDiskNum);
        m_hDisk = CreateFileA(fn, GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ,
            FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL,
            OPEN_EXISTING,
            FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH | FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING, 0);

        if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == m_hDisk)
        {
            return (FAIL);
        }

        //m_DiskInfo.Init();
        return Lock();
    }

    u8 Disk::Lock()
    {
        STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER d1;
        DWORD nr;
        char dn[8], c;

        if (!DeviceIoControl((HANDLE)m_hDisk, IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER,
            NULL, 0, &d1, sizeof(d1), &nr, 0))
        {
            return (FAIL);
        }

        strcpy(dn, "\\\\.\\A:");

        // some volume is hided, so I cannot get its letter
        for (c = 'C'; c < 'Z'; c++)
        {
            HANDLE hd;
            STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER d2;

            dn[4] = c;
            hd = CreateFileA(dn, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

            if (hd == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            {
                continue;
            }

            if ((!DeviceIoControl(hd, IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER,
                NULL, 0, &d2, sizeof(d2), &nr, 0)) ||
                (d1.DeviceType != d2.DeviceType) ||
                (d1.DeviceNumber != d2.DeviceNumber))
            {
                CloseHandle(hd);
                continue;
            }

            if (!DeviceIoControl(hd, FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME, NULL, 0, NULL, 0,
                &nr, 0))
            {
                CloseHandle(hd);
                return (FAIL);
            }

            m_LockedVolums.push_back(hd);
        }

        return (SUCC);
    }

    u8 Disk::UnLock()
    {
        for (auto it : m_LockedVolums)
        {
            CloseHandle(it);
        }

        m_LockedVolums.clear();
        return (SUCC);
    }

    u8 Disk::WriteSector(_Out_opt_ u8 * cBuf, int nStartSec, int nSecCont/* = 1*/)
    {
        if (Seek(nStartSec))
        {
            return(FAIL);
        }

        unsigned long nWrited;

        if ((!WriteFile((HANDLE)m_hDisk, cBuf, nSecCont * m_nBytePerSec, &nWrited, NULL))
            || (nSecCont * m_nBytePerSec != (int)nWrited))
        {
            return(FAIL);
        }

        return(SUCC);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think you’re properly locking the volume.

`FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME` IO control dismounts the file system, but I don’t think it locks it for writing. Use [`FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364575(v=vs.85).aspx) afterwards (or instead, if the volume has no Windows-readable filesystem and therefore wasn’t mounted) to request write access.

P.S. I think you need your app to run elevated to be able to use that API.

Comment: Thank for your answer! But "FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME" is enough for me to write,and my app has ran under "requireAdministrator (/level='requireAdministrator')".To use "FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME"should have the volume letter,but no letter for the hide volume in windows. So That's the problem.

Comment: @yunate Here’s what you can try. Install e.g. HDD raw copy tool. Run it, also run sysinternals process monitor and setup filters to only include events from RawCopy.exe. Use HDD raw copy to write an image to that USB drive. This way, in process monitor, you’ll see what exactly RawCopy.exe did with which file handle, and therefore you can replicate the functionality.